# setAttribute with a loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, setattribute

I am trying to set a src attribute to several images with a loop. I have 8 images and I would like to insert these 8 images into my html. I'am using a for of loop on a array which comes from a JSON files. My JSON seems to be ok, because I can console.log the good values of the attribute source. The values look like this : "images/img1.png". The img1 becomes img2...
The problem is that it put images/img8.png to all the images into the console and just one image in the html.

I tried to put querySelectorAll('.image') but it says `TypeError: img.setAttribute is not a function`.

I tried to put another loop into the for of loop, but it makes an infinite loop, still with images/img8.png.

Here is my code :

```
  .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let img = document.querySelectorAll('.image') 
      for (const item of data) {
        img.setAttribute('src', item.source)
        console.log(img)
      }
    }).catch(err => console.error("Une erreur est survenue", err))
```

Here is my array

```
[
  {
    "image_name": "Image1",
    "image_id": "1",
    "source": "images/img1.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image2",
    "image_id": "2",
    "source": "images/img2.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image3",
    "image_id": "3",
    "source": "images/img3.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image4",
    "image_id": "4",
    "source": "images/img4.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image5",
    "image_id": "5",
    "source": "images/img5.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image6",
    "image_id": "6",
    "source": "images/img6.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image7",
    "image_id": "7",
    "source": "images/img7.png"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image8",
    "image_id": "8",
    "source": "images/img8.png"
  }
]
```

Do you have an idea were the error is ?
Thank you.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.image')` returns a list of elements. You should probably do it by index.

Comment: It would be VERY helpful to see an example of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image'); // a collection 

....
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => data.forEach(({source,image_name},i) => {
    images[i].src = source;
    images[i].alt = image_name;
  })
).catch(err => console.error("Une erreur est survenue", err))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sehx2bc4/

if the images have IDs that match the image_id you can use that instead of the collection and [i]

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => data.forEach(({source,image_name, image_id}) => {
    const image = document.getElementById(image_id);
    image.src = source;
    image.alt = image_name;
  })
).catch(err => console.error("Une erreur est survenue", err))
```

Comment: I have put my array. Sorry for not doing it before. So your code doesn't work because I don't have the same array as you put into the const data. Do you think I shoul chenge my array or there is another way to do with my style of array?

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns an array-like list. You presumably need to iterate that list along with your list of images

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  let img = document.querySelectorAll('.image') 
  for (var i =0;i<data.length;i++) {
    img[i].setAttribute('src', item[i].source)
  }
}).catch(err => console.error("Une erreur est survenue", err))
```